# Lightstreaks on Video Footage

Tags: video, after-effects, special-effects, footage

I'm trying to make this effect for a car video, you can imagine the camera movement for this kind of stuff.

I was going to try [this technique](https://youtu.be/S0mx2jI05y4) which is simply a 3D shape layer in After Effects with a taper.
Right now, I'm doing this above with a 3D Camera Tracker effect which seems to do the job so far, but in the case that I need extra movements such as overtaking the car and going off-screen might be hard to do with a shape layer.

I will be on a deadline and I would like to not follow the wrong strategy wasting time.

[image: example]

Is there anyone who could help me understand the best thing to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you describe "this technique" in words so you're not forcing people to go off-site to watch up to 7 minutes of video to know what you mean.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, I've just edited my post!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get 90% of the way towards the example shown in that video using the free [Saber plugin from videocopilot](https://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/saber_plug-in/). It can't do 3D strokes (for that you would need to use [Red Giant's 3D stroke](https://www.maxon.net/en/red-giant/trapcode-suite/3d-stroke), or some other elaborate method).

Comment: I don't have Trapcode unfortunately, I was thinking of Saber but it only works on masks which are terrible in terms of control and animation.